# How to find the duplicate values in the same row

Tags: sql, oracle

I needed to find the duplicate in the same row.

I have problem like this

```
S.no    ADR_Address                ADR_Nr   
1       Rudolf-Street- 8             8
2       Maxstresst-10                10
```

So you can see the `ADR_Address` and  `ADR_Nr` has the house `Nr` two times.

My task it to find this kind of duplicate values.

Could any one can help me to find using Oracle SQL Statement.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14990842/2142994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LIKE

```
select * from my_table 
where ADR_Address like '%' ||ADR_Nr
```

Comment: @scaisEdge glad it works, can you try to explain what exactly this is doing ?

Comment: @Nudity  .. sure  .. simply  the query looking for the row where the column ADR_Address end with the same value in the column ADR_Nr the like operator look for the value .. the % ignore all the character before the ADR_Nr value  ..the || operator join the wildcard % and the column value ADR_Nr.. hope is clear ..